# What to do in case of "Compilation error: braces around scalar initializer for type 'int'"

Tags: compiler-errors, arduino-uno

I just got my first Arduino, and I'm trying to extend beyond the tutorial and I want to try to make a song with coherent tempos, although the tutorial doesn't explain it :)

this is just one part of the code, and I'm using a passive buzzer btw

```
#include "pitches.h" // these help to just put the notes and not the hertz 
#include "npm.h"     // these ones to control the Notes Per Minute

// notes in the melody:
int melody1[] = {{NOTE_E2, NOTE_HALF},     
                 {NOTE_E2, NOTE_HALF},     
                 {NOTE_F2, NOTE_HALF},     
                 {NOTE_FS2, NOTE_WHOLE},   
                 {NOTE_A2},
                 {NOTE_FS2},
                 {NOTE_A2},
                 {NOTE_FS2},
                 {NOTE_F2},
                 {NOTE_E2},
                 {NOTE_B2},
                 {NOTE_E2},
                 {NOTE_E2}};
                          ↑ that's the brace that is complicating everything ☠️
```

when ever I put it the error in the tittle pops out, but if I erase it another error appears:

```
Compilation error: expected '}' before ';' token
```

it's contradicting itself, idk what to do :|

*don't worry about the note_half and whole, it is not finished cuz i just wanted to check the tempo before i finished so i wouldn't make it all over again, but the error appeared :|

Comment: Why do you have nested braces anyway?  It's an array of ints.  It has elements 0, 1, 2, 3, ...  There is no sense in which the elements are "paired".

Comment: If your program is expecting an array where the even elements contain pitches and the odd elements are durations, then omit all the inner braces and write `int melody[] = { NOTE_E2, NOTE_HALF, NOTE_E2, NOTE_HALF, NOTE_F2, NOTE_HALF, ... };`.  But it's also possible you are adapting this from code that didn't just use an array of `int`, but an array of array of int, or of some more elaborate `struct`.  In which case, you would need to show the code you started from.

Comment: i can show the complete code, it is not that long, but lemme try to do it like you said :)

Comment: You are trying to init the array as it would be a 2D array `int melody1[2][]`.